# Selenium Webdriver python showing error soon after it executes the code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web

When I run my python script which is supposed to open github in edge browser, it works, but closes soon after it is done

```
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

# Change the directory

#Github
def github():
   browser = webdriver.Edge(r'C:\Program Files\Browser Drivers\Edge Drivers\msedgedriver.exe')
   browser.get("https://github.com")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   github()
```

The error

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52908/devtools/browser/7ebfcee1-74f9-43ba-bf79- 
99549f4d7ccf
[2916:7184:0428/150623.910:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)] Every renderer should have at 
least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it 
is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of 
crbug.com/739782.
```